# Which one is used in Mali GPU driver source in Samsung Galaxy Android?

Tags: galaxy, android-kernel, mali

As you know, there are several Mali Midgard directories in Samsung Galaxy's kernel source.

```
drwxrwxrwx@ 141 eee  staff  4512 10 29  2020 b_r10p0
drwxrwxrwx@ 142 eee  staff  4544 10 29  2020 b_r12p0
drwxrwxrwx@ 142 eee  staff  4544 10 29  2020 b_r14p0
drwxrwxrwx@ 149 eee  staff  4768 10 29  2020 b_r16p0
drwxrwxrwx@ 158 eee  staff  5056 10 29  2020 b_r19p0
```

How to know which one is actually used in my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the device.
If you go to chrome://gpu in chrome on your device and scroll down, there will be "Driver Version" in a table. It will be eg 19.0.x rather than r19p0, but the first number will tell you which of the above it is.

Comment: Oh very thank you ~!!